# pyspark, elasticsearch input, can't show dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I can do `df.head()` fine after loading elasticsearch data.
But after I do `withColumn`, I can't do `df.head` or `df.show()`

I can't figure out what's going on, the same `withColumn` code works fine if I create `df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a", 23.0), (3, "B", -23.0)], ("x1", "x2", "x3"))` but not with data from elasticsearch.

I'm using the official demo data (accounts.zip) from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-load-dataset.html

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/usr/local/spark')
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

import pyspark

if 'sc' in locals():
    sc.stop()
conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/elasticsearch-hadoop/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.6.0.jar")
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes.discovery", "true")
#conf.set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.option("es.resource", "relay-foods").format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load()

# ==============> 
# at this state I can print df fine
df.show() # works


from dateutil import parser
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def order_period(order_date):
    order_date = parser.parse(order_date)
    result = order_date.strftime('%Y-%m')

    return result
udf_order_period = udf(order_period, StringType())
df_new2 = df.withColumn("OrderPeriod", udf_order_period("OrderDate"))
# ==================> 
df_new2.head() # this results in error
```

The error messages are

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o152.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (Buffer(_jsonparsefailure, _split_type_failure)) of the type (scala.collection.convert.Wrappers.JListWrapper) cannot be converted to the string type
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1073)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1089)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1127)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1887)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1875)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2108)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2057)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2046)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (Buffer(_jsonparsefailure, _split_type_failure)) of the type (scala.collection.convert.Wrappers.JListWrapper) cannot be converted to the string type
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1073)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1089)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1127)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)
```

Edit

Here's df.show() and df.dtypes

```
+--------------------+--------+--------+----------+-------+----------+-----+------------+------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+----+
|          @timestamp|@version|CommonId| OrderDate|OrderId|PickupDate|PupId|TotalCharges|UserId|             host|             message|                path|sentAt|tags|
+--------------------+--------+--------+----------+-------+----------+-----+------------+------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+----+
|2019-01-28 22:02:...|       1|   2N3WF|03/12/2009|   1937|04/12/2009|    5|    $147.24 | 39588|devserver-MS-7758|1937,03/12/2009,3...|/tmp/relay-foods.csv|  null|null|


[('@timestamp', 'timestamp'),
 ('@version', 'string'),
 ('CommonId', 'string'),
 ('OrderDate', 'string'),
 ('OrderId', 'string'),
 ('PickupDate', 'string'),
 ('PupId', 'string'),
 ('TotalCharges', 'string'),
 ('UserId', 'string'),
 ('host', 'string'),
 ('message', 'string'),
 ('path', 'string'),
 ('sentAt', 'timestamp'),
 ('tags', 'string')]
```

Comment: The `"OrderDate"` passed into the UDF isn't parsable. According to the original `df` schema, what is its data type? Can you give an example of `df.show()` along with the schema - specifically for `"OrderDate"`

Comment: My server is down, I can't print it out, but when I looked at it, it was 'string' type (reported by df.dtypes), and looked like '02/22/2018' ...

Comment: @Tanjin I've added the df.show() and df.dtypes output

Comment: Can you wrap the UDF function in a `try` `except`? Have all the code inside the `try` block and for the `except` block just have `return None`. See how this works.

Comment: Was this solved? Facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Sha yes, it's solved and i tried to look at the solution i have, unfortunately, I can't tell what is the fix looking at my code, 

soly from my memory,

spark is very fragile with data input, and you better check if your input has empty row or something.. if you think your code does follow the convention,, tutorial ,, api etc

Comment: Thanks for your reply @eugene .. Will check :)

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch-hadoop doc :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_querying

try set `es.read.field.as.array.include` config to fix the `JListWrapper cannot be converted to the string type` error

```py
        query = """
                {
                    "query": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    }
                }
            """
        df = (
            self.spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
            .option("es.query", query)
            .option("es.resource", "index_name/_doc")
            .option("es.read.field.as.array.include", "tags")
            .option("es.read.field.exclude", "sentAt")
            .option("es.read.unmapped.fields.ignore", "false")
            .load()
        )
```